# how to store 1000000 digit integers in C++

Tags: c++, types, integer

in my problem i have to save big big integers like upto 1000000 digits and to do some operation. how can i do that.i know that a long int in c++ can store upto 10 digits

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [GMP](http://gmplib.org/), the GNU arbitrary precision library. Just be aware that it's not a very *good* library if you run out of memory.

By that, I mean it will just exit out from underneath you if it cannot allocate memory. I find this an ... interesting ... architectural decision for a general purpose library but it's popular for this sort of stuff so, provided you're willing to wear that restriction, it's probably a good choice.

Another good one is [MPIR](http://www.mpir.org/), a fork of GMP which, despite the name "Multiple Precision Integers and Rationals", handles floating point quite well. I've found these guys far more helpful than the GMP developers when requesting help or suggesting improvements (but, just be aware, that's *my* experience, your mileage may vary).

Comment: Also, MPIR is reported to have better support for (optimized assembly code on) windows, if that is of any concern to the poster.