# C++ numbers add to a negative

Tags: c++

So I was just practicing coding a dynamic solution to the Fibonacci sequence which would return the n'th Fibonacci number and I kept coming across a problem which I can't quite figure out. I am getting two positive numbers adding to a negative!

Code:

```
int fib(int n) {
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(1);
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        v.push_back( v.at(i-1) + v.at(i-2) );
        cout << v.at(i-1) << " + " << v.at(i-2) << " = " << (v.at(i-1) + v.at(i-2)) << endl;
    }
    return v.at(n);
}
```

try running fib(50), note cout is just for debugging

[image]

Comment: You have undefined behaviour due to signed integer overflow.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026104/how-to-store-1000000-digit-integers-in-c?lq=1

Comment: They just don't teach how computers work anymore, do they? No requirement to understand integer arithmetic, signed vs. unsigned.  Only high-level languages so it comes as a surprise when an int simply isn't big enough.

Comment: I come from university like 2 years back, and we learned even in detail how float and doubles work, so they do teach that sort of stuff... guess someone wasn't paying attention though :D

Comment: @CareyGregory, In my experience, no they don't. I picked up programming as a hobby in middle school, and when I got to high school I took both of the programming classes available, and this was never taught. I couldn't tell you if it was taught at my college or not though because I tested out of the programming courses. Certainly wasn't on any of the exams though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change `int` to `unsigned int` or even better `unsigned long long`. Your result is overflowing the maximum value of `int` on your system. Because `int` is signed, when the [most significant bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit) gets set, it becomes a negative number.  See the Stack Overflow question titled [maximum value of int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855459/maximum-value-of-int), and this Swarthmore College page on [binary arithmatic](http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Ref/BinaryMath/BinaryMath.html) for more information. If you're using Visual Studio, take a look at the [Data Type Ranges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) article on MSDN.

In addition to switching to `unsigned long long`, you should probably check for overflow errors such as this and throw an exception. A revised version of your code could look like this.

```
unsigned long long fib(int n) {
    vector<unsigned long long> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(1);
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        if( v.at(i-1) > (std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max() - v.at(i-2)) )
            throw std::overflow_error("number too large to calculate");
        v.push_back( v.at(i-1) + v.at(i-2) );
        cout << v.at(i-1) << " + " << v.at(i-2) << " = " << (v.at(i-1) + v.at(i-2)) << endl;
    }
    return v.at(n);
}
```

You would also want to make sure the code calling your function can handle an exception by using a `try... catch...`. Here's an example

```
try {
    std::cout << "2000th number = " << fib(2000) << std::endl;
} catch( std::overflow_error& ex ) {
    std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl; 
}
```

Comment: "You need to change `int` to `unsigned int` or even better `unsigned long`." Depends on the compiler he's using. I believe that `long` in MSVC is just 4 bytes (not 8). To truly ensure the width of an integer, use the `stdint.h` (or `cstdint`) header file.

Comment: On many platforms int and long are the same size, signed or otherwise.

Comment: @inspector-g, and @Carey Gregory, You're right, I actually meant to type `unsigned long long`. I fixed the answer. I blame it on distraction from watching Brisco County Jr.

Comment: OK, but going to long long just postpones the problem.  A really good answer would address how to avoid (or deal with) integer overflow regardless of the size of the types.  Add that to your answer and I'll +1.

Comment: @CareyGregory, I added checking for overflow, and throwing an `overflow_error` exception.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I actually DID learn about signed vs. unsigned integers, its been a while is all.

By the way, why does the iterator `i` have to be long long?

Comment: @user35039, no it doesn't. Not sure why I changed it.

Answer (score 2):

Because of how C stores your `int` (signed int) in memory, the most significant bit indicates a negative number. So you'll get negative number if you overflow it with large numbers.

Reference:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2%27s_complement

Comment: Which bit is the "first" bit?  And is that the C++ standard?

Comment: This is potentially wrong - see this question's top answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125650/what-do-the-c-and-c-standards-say-about-bit-level-integer-representation-and-m, *[ Example: this International Standard permits 2’s complement, 1’s complement and signed magnitude representations for integral types. —end example ] [§3.9.1/7]*