# Why adding two big integers will get a negative one?

Tags: math

I have tried these in my own computer.

eg. 2000000000+2000000000=-12315555331

I don't know why this doesn't meet the standards, maybe because of the length.

So I'm writing this just to pass the check.

Comment: under my own computer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ numbers add to a negative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680362/c-numbers-add-to-a-negative)

Comment: [Adding two positive integers gives negative answer.Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30934035/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because take longing as an example. The first bit out of the 32 is sign bit, which means the number is negative if it is 1 and positive if 0.